# SQL Server Requery() sometimes hangs

Tags: c++, sql-server, visual-c++, sql-server-2008-r2

I have an issue with Visual C++ and Microsoft SQL Server 2008R2.

The following code will occasionally hang:

```
  Object->Update();

  if(Object->CanRestart())
  {
     //Why does this not return??
     m_pDBRoRBaseObject->Requery();
  }
```

`Object` is derived from `CRecordset`. It looks to me as though a call to `::SQLExecute(m_hstmt)` in the `Requery()` method is hanging, but I can't (with my current skill set anyway) figure out a way around this.

Has anyone had a similar problem, or an insight of any sort?

Comment: Fixed it: due to the architecture, there was an issue with unprotected accesses to shared memory.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to remember (from long, long ago) that Requery - with certain database drivers at least - rebuilds the query as one big IN statement, using the PKs of the rows you have already collected. This may of course be inefficient, depending on your setup, metrics, data etc.etc.

It be worth firing up SQL Profiler and seeing what exactly your Requery() statement is producing.

Comment: Thanks, davek.  As it turns out, I had a shared memory access problem (see above).

Answer (score 0):

Had a shared memory problem...fixed with an event object signaled appropriately.  And a steaming helping of crow.  Tasty!